# java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe with Quartz and MySQL and Tomcat (Tomcat Crash)

Tags: java, mysql, quartz-scheduler, socketexception, job-scheduling

Following is the stack trace.  I read that the Broken Pipe is because of Unclosed connection for 8 hours and the connection close automatically.  I saw this http://itellity.wordpress.com/2011/05/18/getting-rid-of-socketexception-broken-pipe-with-quartz-and-mysql-on-jboss/ .I could not reproduce in my local machine.

1. Is there any way I can reproduce this in my local machine.
2. Will this make a tomact crash? I am using a very old version of quartz jar 1.6.5 and tomcat 6.0.18.  will that be an issue.

Please help me to resolve this issue.

```
[Scheduler_QuartzSchedulerThread] WARN org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreTX - Failed to override connection auto commit/transaction isolation.
com.mysql.jdbc.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure due to underlying exception: 

** BEGIN NESTED EXCEPTION ** 

java.net.SocketException
MESSAGE: Broken pipe

STACKTRACE:

java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:92)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:136)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:65)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:123)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.send(MysqlIO.java:2744)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1612)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:1723)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.execSQL(Connection.java:3277)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.setAutoCommit(Connection.java:5442)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingConnection.setAutoCommit(DelegatingConnection.java:237)
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.AttributeRestoringConnectionInvocationHandler.setAutoCommit(AttributeRestoringConnectionInvocationHandler.java:91)
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.AttributeRestoringConnectionInvocationHandler.invoke(AttributeRestoringConnectionInvocationHandler.java:65)
    at $Proxy4.setAutoCommit(Unknown Source)
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.getConnection(JobStoreSupport.java:711)
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreTX.getNonManagedTXConnection(JobStoreTX.java:72)
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.executeInNonManagedTXLock(JobStoreSupport.java:3757)
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.acquireNextTrigger(JobStoreSupport.java:2729)
    at org.quartz.core.QuartzSchedulerThread.run(QuartzSchedulerThread.java:266)


** END NESTED EXCEPTION **



Last packet sent to the server was 1 ms ago.
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.send(MysqlIO.java:2759)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1612)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:1723)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.execSQL(Connection.java:3277)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.setAutoCommit(Connection.java:5442)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingConnection.setAutoCommit(DelegatingConnection.java:237)
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.AttributeRestoringConnectionInvocationHandler.setAutoCommit(AttributeRestoringConnectionInvocationHandler.java:91)
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.AttributeRestoringConnectionInvocationHandler.invoke(AttributeRestoringConnectionInvocationHandler.java:65)
    at $Proxy4.setAutoCommit(Unknown Source)
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.getConnection(JobStoreSupport.java:711)
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreTX.getNonManagedTXConnection(JobStoreTX.java:72)
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.executeInNonManagedTXLock(JobStoreSupport.java:3757)
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.acquireNextTrigger(JobStoreSupport.java:2729)
    at org.quartz.core.QuartzSchedulerThread.run(QuartzSchedulerThread.java:266)
[Scheduler_QuartzSchedulerThread] WARN org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.AttributeRestoringConnectionInvocationHandler - Failed restore connection's original auto commit setting.
com.mysql.jdbc.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure due to underlying exception: 

** BEGIN NESTED EXCEPTION ** 

java.net.SocketException
MESSAGE: Broken pipe

STACKTRACE:

java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:92)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:136)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:65)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:123)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.send(MysqlIO.java:2744)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1612)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:1723)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.execSQL(Connection.java:3277)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.setAutoCommit(Connection.java:5442)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingConnection.setAutoCommit(DelegatingConnection.java:237)
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.AttributeRestoringConnectionInvocationHandler.restoreOriginalAtributes(AttributeRestoringConnectionInvocationHandler.java:134)
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.cleanupConnection(JobStoreSupport.java:3551)
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.executeInNonManagedTXLock(JobStoreSupport.java:3774)
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.acquireNextTrigger(JobStoreSupport.java:2729)
    at org.quartz.core.QuartzSchedulerThread.run(QuartzSchedulerThread.java:266)


** END NESTED EXCEPTION **



Last packet sent to the server was 0 ms ago.
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.send(MysqlIO.java:2759)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1612)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:1723)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.execSQL(Connection.java:3277)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.setAutoCommit(Connection.java:5442)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingConnection.setAutoCommit(DelegatingConnection.java:237)
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.AttributeRestoringConnectionInvocationHandler.restoreOriginalAtributes(AttributeRestoringConnectionInvocationHandler.java:134)
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.cleanupConnection(JobStoreSupport.java:3551)
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.executeInNonManagedTXLock(JobStoreSupport.java:3774)
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.acquireNextTrigger(JobStoreSupport.java:2729)
    at org.quartz.core.QuartzSchedulerThread.run(QuartzSchedulerThread.java:266)
[Scheduler_QuartzSchedulerThread] ERROR org.quartz.core.ErrorLogger - An error occured while scanning for the next trigger to fire.
org.quartz.JobPersistenceException: Couldn't acquire next trigger: Communications link failure due to underlying exception: 

** BEGIN NESTED EXCEPTION ** 

java.net.SocketException
MESSAGE: Broken pipe

STACKTRACE:

java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:92)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:136)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:65)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:123)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.send(MysqlIO.java:2744)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1612)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:1723)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.execSQL(Connection.java:3277)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.execSQL(Connection.java:3206)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeQuery(PreparedStatement.java:1447)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeQuery(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:177)
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.StdJDBCDelegate.selectTriggerToAcquire(StdJDBCDelegate.java:2924)
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.acquireNextTrigger(JobStoreSupport.java:2747)
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport$36.execute(JobStoreSupport.java:2733)
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.executeInNonManagedTXLock(JobStoreSupport.java:3760)
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.acquireNextTrigger(JobStoreSupport.java:2729)
    at org.quartz.core.QuartzSchedulerThread.run(QuartzSchedulerThread.java:266)


** END NESTED EXCEPTION **



Last packet sent to the server was 1 ms ago. [See nested exception: com.mysql.jdbc.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure due to underlying exception: 

** BEGIN NESTED EXCEPTION ** 

java.net.SocketException
MESSAGE: Broken pipe

STACKTRACE:

java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:92)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:136)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:65)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:123)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.send(MysqlIO.java:2744)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1612)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:1723)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.execSQL(Connection.java:3277)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.execSQL(Connection.java:3206)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeQuery(PreparedStatement.java:1447)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeQuery(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:177)
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.StdJDBCDelegate.selectTriggerToAcquire(StdJDBCDelegate.java:2924)
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.acquireNextTrigger(JobStoreSupport.java:2747)
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport$36.execute(JobStoreSupport.java:2733)
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.executeInNonManagedTXLock(JobStoreSupport.java:3760)
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.acquireNextTrigger(JobStoreSupport.java:2729)
    at org.quartz.core.QuartzSchedulerThread.run(QuartzSchedulerThread.java:266)


** END NESTED EXCEPTION **
```

EDIT:
I am using

```
org.quartz.dataSource.QUARTZ_NO_TX.validateOnCheckout = true
org.quartz.dataSource.QUARTZ_NO_TX.validationQuery = select 1
```

on my quartz properties also

```
autoreconnect=true
```

Is there any way I can reproduce this by changing the mysql properties.  I am getting this only on my server.

Comment: you say you could not solve it from the details in provided link. What exactly did you try? Also, why don't you let it run overnight to accommodate those 8 hours?

Comment: Thanks aldrin for your quick response.  I have edited what I have tried.  I tried leaving it for several hours not 8 hours 4 to 5 hours still I am not getting this error.  Is there any possibility that this will crash the tomcat server?

Comment: I was getting error initially when I add those 2 sentences. So only I told its not working. Now I fixed it.. I will try for 8 hours in testing server and let you know.. Thanks for your reply..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe it is related to [MySQL stale connection](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/connector-j-usagenotes-troubleshooting.html) that is dropped after 8 hours.

EDIT

Read [this](http://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/docs/Server_Configuration_Guide/4/html/Connectors_on_JBoss-Configuring_JDBC_DataSources.html) article.

Make sure you have the following set (not sure about the exact attributes' names but they should be similar to the mentioned below)

1. testWhileIdle=true
2. validationQuery="SELECT 1"
3. minEvictableIdleTimeMillis=1800000
4. timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis=1800000
5. numTestsPerEvictionRun=3

Comment: Thanks for your reply aviad.  The problem is How to avoid this in quartz scheduler.

Comment: @Dilip Rajkumar, You need to configure your application server DataSource properly. See my edit.

Comment: Yes aviad, I am trying with org.quartz.dataSource.myDS.validateOnCheckout = true
org.quartz.dataSource.myDS.validationQuery = select 1  I will let you know after I tested.  Thanks aviad.

Comment: @Dilip Rajkumar, took some time with edit... Please review. Good Luck Dilip!

Comment: Thank you very much aviad.  I will let you know after I try it.

Comment: Hay aviad...  I think I am getting that error again..  do I need to add more code??

Comment: Are you sure that the test queries had ran? You can configure test query to do some inserts in test table , so instead of "SELECT 1" it will insert the current time\date.

Comment: following are my quartz 
org.quartz.dataSource.myDS.maxConnections = 15
org.quartz.dataSource.myDS.validateOnCheckout = true
org.quartz.dataSource.myDS.validationQuery = select 1
org.quartz.dataSource.myDS.testWhileIdle=true
org.quartz.dataSource.myDS.minEvictableIdleTimeMillis=1800000
org.quartz.dataSource.myDS.timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis=1800000
org.quartz.dataSource.myDS.numTestsPerEvictionRun=3

Comment: Am I doing any mistakes in this?